# Button On-Click Event in Xcode 4.2.1

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4.2

I have a static background image (map) that loads in my ImageView.  I have a couple of transparent text images (labels for cities on the map, for example) that I would like to overlay on the map upon the click of a button. re-clicking the button would unload the layer so that the user could have any combination of the layers selected depending upon what they would like to see. I might have a total of 5 layers connected to 5 buttons.

I know it is simple, but I need some help with the button code.  If I have a button called 'cities' and a layer called 'cities.png' I would like to load and display over my main ImageView map, could someone please please please show me some code that would allow the button click to cycle my cities.png layer on and off?

many thanks

Comment: Please show us what you have tried. Not only does that show effort on your part, but it's nigh-impossible for us to give a reasonable answer without having some code context.  (For example, you use the word "layer" without explicitly telling us whether this is a UIView or a CALayer.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Make a property of ImageView and synthesize it
- Add a gesture recognizer to your view(Google it);
- Add a tap count of 1 to fire function
- In function

  check

  ```
      if(self.imageView.image != nil)
      {
       self.ImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@YourImage"]; //load the image view
      }
  else
  {
  self.imageView.image = nil; //image already dispelled..remove it.
  self.imageview.center = //touch location center //
  }
  ```

This will work if you want to load one image at a time

Comment: i appreciate the feedback.  I'll see what I can put together with this direction.

Comment: Also image view.center shoul be in if part and if part should be changed to ==nil . Am on my phone so will edit it later

Comment: i want to thank you again for the code sample above.  I got my app working as planned thanks to your input. cheers.